# Github Actions stays stuck on a task and finally fail on timeout

Tags: python, github, pip, github-actions

For the [ruptures](https://github.com/deepcharles/ruptures) python package, we are using Github Actions to run our tests on each PR that should be merged on `master`. It worked beautifully up until now. But since few days, this Gh Actions just stays stuck and finally fails on a timeout (360 minutes).

Please, find [here](https://github.com/deepcharles/ruptures/actions/runs/785660227) an example of the symptoms on a particular run.

Please, find [here](https://github.com/deepcharles/ruptures/blob/master/.github/workflows/run-test.yml) the Gh Actions code that performs the tests. It has a `strategy matrix` on several python versions and os.

```
name: Run tests

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9]
        os: [ubuntu-latest, windows-latest, macos-latest]
        exclude:
          - os: windows-latest
            python-version: 3.9
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Install ruptures
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        python -m pip install .[test]
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        python -m pytest
```

From what I can see, there is no error except just it stays stuck. From what I noticed, it stays stuck always on the first elements of the `strategy matrix` combination, i.e. for us it is python v3.6 (which is the lowest in the matrix possibilities). But again, not sure it is linked to that since no error, just a timeout with no specific message about something going wrong (unless I did not looked to the right place).

Since I thought it might be linked to Gh getting lost with too many combination jobs on the `matrix`, I tried specifying `max-parallel: 2` in the `strategy`. But it did not solved anything.

For the same reason, I tried removing from the `strategy matrix` the python v3.6 in order to see if the python v3.6 was the particular issue. But it does not solve anything and the Gh Actions just stays stuck on the Python v3.7 instead of v3.6. See [here](https://github.com/deepcharles/ruptures/runs/2455568667) to see the run.

Tests run smoothly locally.

I don't get what cause this behaviour, even more since this Gh Actions used to run without any problem for several months.

Comment: FYI, I tried to flatten the `matrix` on the OS dimension by instead listing 3 jobs. So the `matrix` had only the python version dimension left. It did not solve anything. See [here](https://github.com/deepcharles/ruptures/actions/runs/795305328) for the run.

Comment: It looks like it's an issue related to `pip`... very strange: https://github.com/deepcharles/ruptures/runs/2445729836?check_suite_focus=true#step:4:17

Comment: Is there a particular reason for upgrading pip? Could you omit that step and see what happens?

Comment: Thanks a lot @jidicula for the comment. I was able to investigate and found a working solution !

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [jidicula](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6310633/jidicula), I was able to investigate and find a solution.

**Bottom line :**

- It has nothing to do with Github Actions
- It is entirely related to `pip`

**Solutions :**

Instead of upgrading `pip` using `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`, set manually the version to the last working version `python -m pip install pip==21.0.1`. In details :

- In our particular case, upgrading pip would give the `v21.1` version
- The last version of `pip` that allowed the Gh Actions to run smoothly was `v21.0.1`. So I just now set manually `pip` to this particular value

**Explanations :**

It seems like there is an issue with the new (`v21.1`) `pip` version

In the [failing Gh Actions](https://github.com/deepcharles/ruptures/actions/runs/798695169), there was the following message :

```
Processing /home/runner/work/ruptures/ruptures
  DEPRECATION: A future pip version will change local packages to be built in-place without first copying to a temporary directory. We recommend you use --use-feature=in-tree-build to test your packages with this new behaviour before it becomes the default.
   pip 21.3 will remove support for this functionality. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7555.
```

Nevertheless, once `pip` is upgraded to `v21.1`, adding or not adding the `--use-feature=in-tree-build` did not solved anything and `pip` just stayed stuck.

Related also the the use of `--use-feature=in-tree-build` I found [this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2195) issue on `pip` repo. This very last issue has a comment that proposes to do

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
pip install dist/*.whl
```

instead of `pip install .` which is not a good solution in our particular case since we are making use of the possibility to specify a `[options.extras_require]` like for instance `python -m pip install .[test]`. But it might help in your case !

Finally, for more details on the underlying bug in `pip`, please find [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9617) the issue grouping several related behaviours.